# Why is my .htaccess rewrite rule not working?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https, url-rewriting, redirect

Why is my .htaccess rewrite rule not working? I do not want the entire domain to be https, only a couple of urls such as login and one other. Below is my htaccess file.

Rewrite works for entire domain but when I change it to only the specific file it does nothing. Please let me know how to correct his?

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domainname.org/$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*user_login)$ https://domainname.org/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: That is my full .htaccess

Comment: full URL is ex http://domainname.org/index.php?main_page=user_login
#  I used domainname for privacy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to put your query string in the expression of your `RewriteRule` directive. Try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^main_page=user_login$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ https://domainname.org%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: I was able to add the second condition (user_login|inventory_results)